# About graph of a Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have been dealing with the following question, but could not find the answer. How can I solve ?

**Question:** Let $f\colon\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable function and $E:=\{(x,f(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be graph of the function. If $\operatorname{esssup}\{|f(x)| : x \in [-n,n] \} < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for each $\epsilon > 0$
there exists a Lebesgue measurable set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $E \subset K$ and $\operatorname{Area}(K) < \epsilon$.

**EDIT: My idea is that**

Let $\{(a_i,b_i)\}$ be a sequence covering $\mathbb{R}$ with $b_i−a_i=1, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define $$K_i:=\{(x,f(x)−\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+2}})\times(x,f(x)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+2}}) \mid x \in (a_i,b_i)\}$$

Then $K = \bigcup_i K_i$ covers $E$ and

$$\lambda(K) \leq \sum_i(b_i−a_i)\frac{2\epsilon}{2^{i+2}}= \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon.$$

If it is true, can you tell me in which step I used essentially boundedness of $f$ ?

Since $f(x)$ is essentially bounded, $\lambda((f(x)+\epsilon) - (f(x)-\epsilon))=2\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Since a continuous function may have HAusdorff dimension 2 (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23960/how-big-can-the-hausdorff-dimension-of-a-function-graph-get)), the answer to your question is NO.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.